# How to use leaflet for image viewing and reloading images at zoom

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to built an image viewer which reloads images at every zoom level, to not load really large images, and also retain the sharpness of the image. See this example: https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/nl/rijksstudio/kunstenaars/rembrandt-van-rijn/objecten#/SK-C-5,0

I did some research and found out I can use leaflet.js for this. I initially load the 1024x1024 image and when I zoom in leaflet.js needs to load 4 new images that make up the whole image. Zooming in again and you get the same.

The problem is that I don't get it to work. I have the following code:

```js
var map = L.map('image-map', {
  maxZoom: 20,
  minZoom: 20,
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).setView([0, 0], 20);



var southWest = map.unproject([0, 1024], map.getMaxZoom());
var northEast = map.unproject([1024, 0], map.getMaxZoom());
map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast));

L.tileLayer('/map-tiles/map_{x}_{y}.jpg', {

}).addTo(map);
```

```css
#image-map {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
  crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg=="
  crossorigin=""></script>



<div id="image-map"></div>
```

But for some reason nothing gets loaded now. I use this link as an example: http://omarriott.com/aux/leaflet-js-non-geographical-imagery/#using-the-tiles-in-leaflet

Does anyone know how to fix this issue or another way to implement this?

EDIT: I found this link: https://medium.com/@jarednielsen/how-to-make-an-interactive-story-map-using-leaflet-and-non-geographical-images-821f49ff3b0d

It has the same functionality that I want. Also the source JS files are very clear, and is very useful to figure out. I will try this myself and I hope that I can make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it seem work (I can see tiles query in network log) when zoom is 1 or arround.

I have found an other article from leaflet here : https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html

And, for information, you can remove zoom control with "zoomControl"

```
var map = L.map('image-map', {
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 1,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    zoomControl: false
}).setView([0, 0], 1);
```

**Seem to work** (can see requests in console)

```js
var map = L.map('image-map', {
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 1,
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).setView([0, 0], 1);

var southWest = map.unproject([0, 1024], map.getMaxZoom());
var northEast = map.unproject([1024, 0], map.getMaxZoom());
map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast));

L.tileLayer('/map-tiles/map_{x}_{y}.jpg', {

}).addTo(map);
```

```css
#image-map {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
  crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg=="
  crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="image-map"></div>
```

**Seem to not work** (can't see requests in console)

```js
var map = L.map('image-map', {
  minZoom: 20,
  maxZoom: 20,
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).setView([0, 0], 20);

var southWest = map.unproject([0, 1024], map.getMaxZoom());
var northEast = map.unproject([1024, 0], map.getMaxZoom());
map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast));

L.tileLayer('/map-tiles/map_{x}_{y}.jpg', {

}).addTo(map);
```

```css
#image-map {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
  crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg=="
  crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="image-map"></div>
```

Comment: You just included an empty map container.

Comment: No, I only change the zoom values. If you open your browser network console and run my snippet, you will see network request to tiles :
- GET /map-tiles/map_-1_-1.jpg, GET /map-tiles/map_0_-1.jpg...
If you change minZoom, maxZoom and currentZoom to 20, tiles requests are not made and you will see nothing in the console.

Comment: I see the snippet, and i see the requests are being made. But the weird thing is, I only want to load these images based on zoom level. I don't know how to do this. I want to have at zoom 1, 1 image, at zoom 2, 4 images, etc. to make up the whole image, but without the high image size, because the image is cut up